# What does 'System.ConfigItem.ObjectStatusEnum.Active' represent in SCOM

Tags: scom

I query the following SCOM endpoint: `OperationsManager/data/objectInformation/<object id>`

Among the response properties, I receive the following property:

```
  <MonitoringObjectProperty>
     <name>Object Status</name>
     <value>System.ConfigItem.ObjectStatusEnum.Active</value>
  </MonitoringObjectProperty>
```

I want to know what this property represents. I am looking for a way to query the API to figure out if a given server is running or not (crashed/network disconnected etc) & wondering if this property represents this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It is not used in SCOM, its leftover from System Center Service Manager.  Back in 2012 when they built Service Manager SCSM they used the code base from SCOM 2012.  Then they merged the updated code SCSM back into SCOM (for some unknown reason) this created a bunch of useless properties and tables in the SCOM DB.

Many of these fields can still be updated manually with PowerShell but I would not recommend it.

Here is a link for more information.  [Using the Asset Status Property in SCOM](https://randomnote1.github.io/scom/using-the-asset-status-property-in-scom/)

Here is how you can use the API to get server status.  [SCOM REST API to get Windows/Linux machine's availability (whether the server is running & reachable)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65025335/scom-rest-api-to-get-windows-linux-machines-availability-whether-the-server-is)